# How to configure Xcode's SSH client?

Tags: macos, xcode, ssh, git

We've enabled SSH certificates for all repositories in our private GitHub organization recently. To use certificates, I've added `CertificateFile` keyword to the SSH configuration file in my home directory:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile     ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    CertificateFile  ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

Fetching, cloning, pushing a git repo on the command line works fine. But when I open an Xcode project, which uses Swift Package Manager (SPM) to depend on a git repository in our private GitHub organization, Xcode fails to fetch the repository.

It seems to me that Xcode uses a different/proprietary SSH client, which is not configured to use certificates. Is it possible to configure SSH in Xcode?